# MySQL Count on grouped by subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to make a SQL query on some flights (called legs). The goal is to know how many flights are on time, how many have between 5 and 15 mins of delay and how many more than 15.

Using subqueries, I managed to get a first result :

```
SELECT 
    count(*) as 'leg total',
    leg2.l2count as 'less than 15min delay',
    round(leg2.l2count / count(*) * 100, 2) as 'less than 15min delay percentage',
    leg3.l3count as 'more than 15min delay',
    round(leg3.l3count / count(*) * 100, 2) as 'more than 15min delay percentage',
    count(*) - leg2.l2count - leg3.l3count as 'on time',
    round((count(*) - leg2.l2count - leg3.l3count) / count(*) * 100, 2) as 'on time percentage' 
FROM TBL_leg leg -- previsional dates
JOIN TBL_flight_reports fr ON leg.id = fr.leg_ops_id, -- realized dates
(
    SELECT count(l2.id) as l2count
    FROM TBL_leg l2
    JOIN TBL_flight_reports fr2 ON l2.id = fr2.leg_ops_id
    WHERE (
        timediff(fr2.arrival_date_block, l2.to_date_time) > SEC_TO_TIME(5*60) AND
        timediff(fr2.arrival_date_block, l2.to_date_time) < SEC_TO_TIME(15*60)
    )
    OR (
        timediff(fr2.departure_date_block, l2.start_date_time) > SEC_TO_TIME(5*60) AND
        timediff(fr2.departure_date_block, l2.start_date_time) < SEC_TO_TIME(15*60)
    )
) leg2, -- delays between threshold and 15min
(
    SELECT count(l3.id) as l3count
    FROM TBL_leg l3
    JOIN TBL_flight_reports fr3 ON l3.id = fr3.leg_ops_id
    WHERE (
        timediff(fr3.arrival_date_block, l3.to_date_time) > SEC_TO_TIME(15*60)
    )
    OR (
        timediff(fr3.departure_date_block, l3.start_date_time) > SEC_TO_TIME(15*60)
    )
) leg3 -- delays of more than 15min
;
```

This query seems to be fine.

Now, i'm trying to sort my results : in my TBL_leg table, there is an airplane_id column and I want to group my results by it. The goal being to have my delays by airplane.

The issue is getting my grouping in my subqueries. I'm missing some logic right there.

Also, if you have some better solution for my main issue (my current query), feel free :)

Regards

Comment: I can't tell what your question is.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation all help.

Comment: My current query gives me the total count of legs, count of legs with 5 to 15 min of Delay and more than 15min of delay.

I want to add a Group By clause in order to have the delays by airplane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure each sub query is grouped by the airplane id and add the airplane id to the select of the sub query and then join by the airplane id.

e.g. 2nd leg:

```
left join (
    SELECT l2.airplane_id, count(l2.id) as l2count
    FROM TBL_leg l2
    JOIN TBL_flight_reports fr2 ON l2.id = fr2.leg_ops_id
    WHERE (
        timediff(fr2.arrival_date_block, l2.to_date_time) > SEC_TO_TIME(5*60) AND
        timediff(fr2.arrival_date_block, l2.to_date_time) < SEC_TO_TIME(15*60)
    )
    OR (
        timediff(fr2.departure_date_block, l2.start_date_time) > SEC_TO_TIME(5*60) AND
        timediff(fr2.departure_date_block, l2.start_date_time) < SEC_TO_TIME(15*60)
    )
    GROUP BY l2.airplane_id
) leg2 ON leg.airplane_id = leg2.airplane_id
```

Group the total query on airplane_id as well.